How to declare variable inside while loop condition in c++ ? Is this even possible?
I am trying to write a c++ program in the most clean way possible. The code snippet looks something like this :
int result = 0;
while ((result = (fullBottles / numExchange)) >= numExchange)
      {
        ans += result;
        fullBottles = result;
      }

Although, the above code snippet is still clean. But how can i achieve this ?
while ((int result = (fullBottles / numExchange)) >= numExchange)
      {
        ans += result;
        fullBottles = result;
      }

Because I don't have any use of the variable result after the loop. So, I want it to get destroyed as soon as the loop exists. How can i do that ?

You can just put your whole while loop in a { }

Also always post a [mcve] with all the variables used declared/defined.

Dupe: Some way to declare variable inside while condition? Both of the solutions given below are in the dupe.

"I want it to get destroyed as soon as the loop exists." - Is result in your actual code an object of a complex class ? Otherwise why do need it destroyed (it doesn't even have a real meaning for an int) ?

It is not limited to while-loops, (int i = 0) is just not a valid expression - syntax error.

@BoP but for if since C++ 17 we have if with init-statement which is not available for while.

@wohlstad - Yes, but then it is a statement, not an expression. if ((int i = 0)) is also an error. Details, details...  :-)

@BoP I meant that if while supported a similar construct (with an init statement, similar to if) it could solve the OP's issue.

Just place the variable definition and the while in a separate block (i.e.  between a { and a }).   Or, better, place them in a separate function (and name that function so it is clear what it achieves).

IMHO, declaring variables in a while expression makes debugging more difficult and makes scoping rules more difficult to follow.  I prefer to use constant temporary variables before the while loop, so when I set a breakpoint at the while loop, I can see the expression limit before the loop starts.

You could use a for loop:
for (int result; (result = (fullBottles / numExchange)) >= numExchange;) {
    ans += result;
    fullBottles = result;
}


One option is to put your whole while loop in a new scope { }(sometimes called as anonymous block) as shown below:
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    {                       //new scope starts here
        int result = 0;  
        while(result <10)
        {
            i++;
            std::cout << i;
            result++;
        }
    }                          //new scope ends here
    //result cannot be used here
}


With this technique, you can set a breakpoint at the while loop and easily view the result variable.  IMHO, much better than declaring or assigning values to variables in a while expression.  +1

@ThomasMatthews Yeah, I agree. Thanks.
